# SQL Data reader returning wrong date

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sqldatareader

I'm working on an Excel add in, retrieving data from a SQL Server database and inserting it into Excel.

In the database I have a date `2013-06-01` (YYYY-MM-DD)

When reading from the database using `SqlDataReader`, the following command:

```
myReader.GetValue(c)
```

Returns `06/01/2013` (DD-MM-YYYY), when is then stored in Excel taking 6 as the day and 1 as the month number

Any ideas what could be going on?

Thanks

Comment: What **datatype** is your SQL Server column? It ought to be `DATE` or `DATETIME`, and then you should be able to properly read it using `myReader.GetDateTime(c)`

Comment: it's dateTime, myReader.GetDateTime(c) still returns the wrong value 06/01/2013

Comment: When you are putting it into excel, can you not just reformat the datetime as a string: myReader.GetDateTime(c).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior seems to be produced by a different Localization configuration between the SQL Server and Microsoft Excel.

If you can't change this configuration, I suggest you to use a `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` for the SQL statement that you are using to retrieve the data.

In example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, Date_Column, 103) AS UsingConvertFrom_DDMMYYYY
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Using this approach (that is **not the best**), you are forcing the value of the DataReader.GetValue to use the original value "*well parsed*".

You can check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx#United%20States%20%28English%29) documentation for more details.

Comment: the problem is before the date goes to excel, its in the DataReader that the date is read wrongly

Comment: SQL stores the date as a date, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

This could be an issue regarding the localization.
You can both set a localization to the SQL connection and the system you are working on, even the column-specification in excel.
My best guess would be to check wether the settings are fine.